# Understanding bbswitch and nvidia kernel module

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, bumblebee, bbswitch

I have a laptop with a GTX 970M dGPU and an Intel GMA iGPU. I currently have the proprietary `nvidia` drivers installed (no `nouveau`) as well as `bumblebee` and `bbswitch`.

Basically, I want the laptop to use the iGPU by default, and be able to switch to the dGPU on the fly (either app-based or manual switch). Also, ideally I want to have the `nvidia` proprietary driver managing my dGPU.

It looks like `bbswitch` cannot work unless the `nvidia` kernel module is unloaded. To be honest, I'm still a Linux beginner, and I'm not 100% sure what the `nvidia` kernel module does, and how it relates to the `nvidia` driver.

So here are my questions:

- Do I want my system to unload the `nvidia` kernel module to use `bbswitch`?
- By unloading the `nvidia` kernel module, is it the same thing as not having the `nvidia` proprietary driver installed/running?
- (And ultimately) how do I get to my desired setup?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the NVIDIA drivers and remove "bumblebee" as well.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest official NVIDIA drivers 358 and "nvidia-prime".

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Use NVIDIA X Server Settings (Prime Profiles) to switch between the intel and NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: @oaskamay - did this answer already work fully ?! nvidia is famous for different possibilities (included unwanted short-circuits) ...